# How to find Code name from given numbers using in SQL(Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I have millions of numbers with different digits 3 to 8 (121, 1123, 12345678 etc.)
Which is nothing but

```
1 st code    + 2nd Code  +   3rd Code    = Number
     "1"     +     "2"   +      "1"      = 121
    "123"    +     "45"  +      "678"    = 1234567
    "1234"   +      ""   +      ""       = 1234
```

2nd and 3rd code may be blank

i have another table with 1st code as a primary key and Code name

In SQL (Oracle), I have to find out Code name from each number.
I don't care about 2nd code and 3rd code, If there is longest match found considering whole number as a 1st code

What is the best approach with respect to performance?

Comment: How can you tell that 1234567 is 123 + 45 + 678 and not 1234 + 56 + 78?

Comment: For this to work you need either a delamination character (like `|` or `,` etc) between field values or you need to use fixed width for your fields like left padding each value with the character `0`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In that case i am fine with 1234 or 12345 or even 123456 as a company code..longest match.

Comment: So you do not care what it matches? So if the first record lets change `Employee code` to have value of `3`. The resulting `Number` would then be matched to the wrong record based on that logic and there would be no match for department or employee.

Comment: Yes, Actually company, dept, employee's are just placeholder.

Comment: So why even include them?

Comment: I have updated my query

Comment: Use a direct equality comparison of `1st code` and the number parameter. If you get no results trim the `number` value by 1 and do another query. Continue this until there is a match.

Answer (score 1):

give this one a try, maybe this simple solution is fast enough for you?

```
-- assuming primary key in lookup table is a number
select subq.num,subq.matching_firstcode, 
       (select codename from codes ci where ci.firstcode = subq.matching_firstcode) codename
from (
    select n.num, 
    greatest(
        nvl(c8.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c7.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c6.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c5.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c4.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c3.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c2.firstcode,0),
        nvl(c1.firstcode,0)
    ) matching_firstcode
    from numbers n
    left outer join codes c1 on c1.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 1))
    left outer join codes c2 on c2.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 2))
    left outer join codes c3 on c3.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 3))
    left outer join codes c4 on c4.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 4))
    left outer join codes c5 on c5.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 5))
    left outer join codes c6 on c6.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 6))
    left outer join codes c7 on c7.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 7))
    left outer join codes c8 on c8.firstcode = to_number(substr(to_char(n.num), 1, 8))
) subq
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/443624/1/0

Comment: A nice way to avoid converting both sides of comparison to text, and do that only on one side. I'm tempted to try a variation, that would avoid conversion completely (e.g. by division).

Answer (score 1):

If you are preferring a longest match, I would try something like this:

```
select n.num,
       max(c.firstcode) keep (dense_rank last order by length(c.firstcode)) as firstcode,
       max(c.codename) keep (dense_rank last order by length(c.firstcode)) as codename
  from numbers n
  left join codes c on n.num like c.firstcode || '%'
 group by n.num
 order by 1, 2;
```

I've used basically the same table structure and data as @[Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10300113) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52228076/5853770)'s fiddle.
I've also used implicit casts to character types, for brevity, although I'd suggest explicit casts instead (for clarity), e.g. `length(to_char(c.firstcode))` instead of just `length(c.firstcode)` and `to_char(n.num) like to_char(c.firstcode) || '%'` instead of `n.num like c.firstcode || '%'`.

Sample data used:
Table "numbers":

```
+---------+
|     NUM |
+---------+
|     121 |
|     765 |
|    1234 |
|    3124 |
| 1234567 |
| 3124567 |
+---------+
```

Table "codes":

```
+-----------+----------+
| FIRSTCODE | CODENAME |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | A        |
|       123 | B        |
|       312 | C        |
|      3124 | D        |
+-----------+----------+
```

Result of the query:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
|     NUM | FIRSTCODE | CODENAME |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|     121 |         1 | A        |
|     765 |           |          |
|    1234 |       123 | B        |
|    3124 |      3124 | D        |
| 1234567 |       123 | B        |
| 3124567 |      3124 | D        |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/958fed/1

**Edit**: This query would benefit from the "num" and "firstcode" columns being character columns (and indexed) instead of numerical ones.

Comment: Nice use of the analytical function and only joining codes once. Looking at the execution plans on sql fiddle yours should be faster. Maybe OP can try both on his data set and let us know?

Comment: @Peter: This actually is not using analytical functions, but aggregate functions, but this is a common mistake. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) for reference.